# Rails strange behavior with build association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a product model that belongs to Brand

```
Model product
belongs_to :brand

model Brand 
has_one :product
```

on product create i place a select brand on creation

```
    <%=  p.collection_select(:brand_id, Brand.all, :id, :name, {},{ :multiple => false}) %>
```

but if the user would like to add his brand i added a text field

```
 <%= p.fields_for  :brand_attributes  do |b| %>

  <%=b.text_field :name, :label=>"Name"%>
<% end %>
```

now, if the user choose the brand on select did not show on product show page
just if the user add the name of the brand

so, is possible to keep a select brand and the possibility do add the brand name to?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you will need to add some additional logic in the controller method to cater for either situation. You've posted minimal code so it would help if you showed the controller method that the form posts to.

Also are you sure the relationship should be `has_one`? From your form and the fact that you're showing all the brands to allow the user to select one that may have already been selected for another product, which would explain why the brand isn't appearing on the show page. You may want a `has_many` relationship.